# Getting "Bad request" error or "NoRegisteredProviderFound" while deploying Key Vault Certificate (self signed) into Web App

Tags: certificate, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

Created Key-Vault & provided the authorization to the RP Service Principal (application registered at AzureAD) by executing the Power Shell command. Key-Vault details is given below -

```
Vault Name : MyKeyVaultTest
```

Resource ID: /subscriptions/*****-*****-*****-*****-**********/resourceGroups/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/ providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/MyKeyVaultTest
Access Policies : 
   Tenant ID                                  : d29bcd12-3280-4f37-b8f2-6e9e2f581472
   Object ID                                  : daccd2fd-835a-4c03-8336-c5fcf481f3cc
   Application ID                             : 172f36fc-a098-47a1-9c83-04016d3e9781
   Permissions to Keys                        : Get, List, Update, Create, Import, Delete, Recover, Backup, Restore, Decrypt, Encrypt, UnwrapKey, WrapKey, Verify, Sign, Purge
   Permissions to Secrets                     : Get, List, Set, Delete, Recover, Backup, Restore, Purge
   Permissions to Certificates                : Get, List, Update, Create, Import, Delete, ManageContacts, ManageIssuers, GetIssuers, ListIssuers, SetIssuers, DeleteIssuers
   Permissions to (Key Vault Managed) Storage :

Created a self signed Certificate using below mentioned Power Shell script -

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname XXXXXXXtechmahindra.onmicrosoft.com
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String ‘XXXXXX@1234@’ -Force -AsPlainText
$path = 'cert:\localmachine\my\' + $cert.thumbprint 
Export-PfxCertificate -cert $path -FilePath c:\temp\cert.pfx -Password $pwd
```

Added same certificate to Key-Vault and got the Secret named "mykeyvaulttestwebappPK" having content type "application/x-pkcs12.

Then enable ARM Client and executing below mentioned script to deploy Key Vault Certificate into Web App named "MyKeyVaultTestWebApp" which is giving error. Script and Errors are given below -

```
1. Script without changing the API version:

ARMClient.exe PUT /subscriptions/*****-*****-*****-*****-**********/resourceGroups/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/keyvaultcertificate?api-version=2016-03-01 "{'Location':'SouthCentralUS','Properties':{'KeyVaultId':'/subscriptions/*****-*****-*****-*****-**********/resourceGroups/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/MyKeyVaultTest', 'KeyVaultSecretName':'mykeyvaulttestwebappPK', 'serverFarmId':'/subscriptions/*****-*****-*****-*****-**********/resourceGroups/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/MyKeyVaultTestWebAppServicePlan'}}"

"Code": "BadRequest",
"Message": "The service does not have access to '/subscriptions/*****-*****-*****-*****-**********/resourcegroups/rg-scotia-scale-test/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/mykeyvaulttest' Key Vault. Please make sure that you have granted necessary permissions to the service to perform the request operation."

2. Script with the Serverfarm’s API version:

ARMClient.exe PUT /subscriptions/*****-*****-*****-*****-**********/resourceGroups/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/keyvaultcertificate?api-version=2016-09-01 "{'Location':'SouthCentralUS','Properties':{'KeyVaultId':'/subscriptions/*****-*****-*****-*****-**********/resourceGroups/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/MyKeyVaultTest', 'KeyVaultSecretName':'mykeyvaulttestwebappPK', 'serverFarmId':'/subscriptions/*****-*****-*****-*****-**********/resourceGroups/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/MyKeyVaultTestWebAppServicePlan'}}"

"code": "NoRegisteredProviderFound",
"message": "No registered resource provider found for location 'SouthCentralUS' and API version '2016-09-01' for type 'certificates'.


3. Script with the Key-Vault’s API version:

ARMClient.exe PUT /subscriptions/*****-*****-*****-*****-**********/resourceGroups/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/keyvaultcertificate?api-version=2015-06-01 "{'Location':'SouthCentralUS','Properties':{'KeyVaultId':'/subscriptions/*****-*****-*****-*****-**********/resourceGroups/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/MyKeyVaultTest', 'KeyVaultSecretName':'mykeyvaulttestwebappPK', 'serverFarmId':'/subscriptions/*****-*****-*****-*****-**********/resourceGroups/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/MyKeyVaultTestWebAppServicePlan'}}"

"Code": "BadRequest",
"Message": "The service does not have access to '/subscriptions/*****-*****-*****-*****-**********/resourcegroups/rg-scotia-scale-test/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/mykeyvaulttest' Key Vault. Please make sure that you have granted necessary permissions to the service to perform the request operation."
```

---

[N.B.: Referred "https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/05/24/deploying-azure-web-app-certificate-through-key-vault/" used to implement the changes]

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, I guess you may not enable the 'Microsoft.Web' Resource Provider directly access the azure key Vault.

So you will face you could have the enough permission to access to the key vault error.

I suggest you could follow below powershell codes to enable the permission.

Then you could set the certificate in azure web app.

Codes like this:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount 
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID 
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName KEY_VAULT_NAME -ServicePrincipalName abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd -PermissionsToSecrets get
```

Then you could call this codes to add the certificate:

```
ARMClient.exe PUT /subscriptions/*****-*****-*****-*****-**********/resourceGroups/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/keyvaultcertificate?api-version=2016-03-01 "{'Location':'SouthCentralUS','Properties':{'KeyVaultId':'/subscriptions/*****-*****-*****-*****-**********/resourceGroups/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/MyKeyVaultTest', 'KeyVaultSecretName':'mykeyvaulttestwebappPK', 'serverFarmId':'/subscriptions/*****-*****-*****-*****-**********/resourceGroups/XXX-YYY-ZZZ/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/MyKeyVaultTestWebAppServicePlan'}}"
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tried, but still getting same error...

PS C:\Windows\system32> $servicePrincipal = New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId 172f36fc-a098-47a1-9c83-04016d3e9781

PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName MyKeyVaultTest -ObjectId  $servicePrincipal.Id -PermissionsToKeys all -PermissionsToSecrets all
WARNING: The 'all' permission is being deprecated and does not include the 'purge' permission. 'Purge' permission must be explicitly set.

PS C:\Windows\system32> $ServicePrincipal.ApplicationId #Outputs the ServicePrincipalName/AppPrincipalId

Comment: Don't change my PS code, the  ServicePrincipalName abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd means azure web app service.Please copy my codes(just change the keyvault name) and try again.