# How to add a public key certificate using AZ CLI

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml

I can easily add my public key certificate to my WebApp using the portal:
MyWebApp --> Certificates --> Public key certificate --> Add certificate.

I need to do the same using AZ CLI.
I already understand such a dedicated command doesn't exist, but I should be able to use `az resource create`.

I've been trying with numerous variations for days but can't get it to work.
This is my YAML task:

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Add Public Certificate to App Service
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: "${{ parameters.SubscriptionName }}"
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: >           
      az resource create 
      --resource-group $(ResourceGroupName) 
      --name "my-wa/ServicePublicKey" 
      --resource-type "Microsoft.Web/sites/publicCertificates"  
      --is-full-object 
      --api-version "2022-09-01"
      --properties '{\"existingWebAppName\":\"my-wa\", \"location\":\"West Europe\", \"blob\":\"MIIC/zCCAeugAwIBAgIQjngbV7+4eppN1YUvFh8guDAJBgUrDgMCHQUAMBgx...FjAUBgNVBAMTDXRlc3RjZX8\",\"publicCertificateLocation\":\"CurrentUserMy\"}'
```

It seems my JSON is OK, but I now get this error:

```
ERROR: Operation returned an invalid status 'Not Found'
```

Sadly it doesn't tell me what it can't find.
I can't find any other example about how to add a public key certificate to my WebApp.

Comment: Maybe you can refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63167393/16162444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of **`az rest`** command and call this [Azure Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/certificates/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0) to update the certificate to your web app, Make sure the service principal or Azure Resource manager service connection you're using to add the certificate has necessary permissions on the Key vault to access the certificate.As my certificate is stored in the Key vault certificate. I am using default Azure Resource manager service connection as my azureSubscription.

**My YAML script with Azure CLI task:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xxx subscription(10)(xxxx6-xxxxcb2a7)'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      az account set --subscription "Subscription Name"
      az account show
      az rest --method put --body '{
        "location": "australiaeast",
        "properties": {
          "keyVaultId": "/subscriptions/xxxx98-44d6-xxxx97cb2a7/resourceGroups/valleyrg54/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/valleykv9",
          "keyVaultSecretName": "siliconcert",
          "serverFarmId": "/subscriptions/xxx-f598-xxxx-xx7cb2a7/resourceGroups/valleyrg54/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/ASP-valleyrg54-8a96"
        },
        "tags": {
          "environment": "production",
          "owner": "john.doe"
        }
      }' --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx65-xx-xxxfd-xxx97cb2a7/resourceGroups/valleyrg54/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/siliconcert?api-version=2022-03-01 --headers "Content-Type=application/json"
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

If you face any permission error, Refer this [SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405578/getting-bad-request-error-or-noregisteredproviderfound-while-deploying-key-v#) by Brando Zhang

One workaround is to use [Azure Powershell command SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63156594/upload-public-certificate-to-azure-function-app-using-a-cli/63167393#63167393) as suggested by Miao Tian-MSFT

**Here, I have the .cer certificate in my Azure repository:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'PowershellSid'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      # Install the specific version of Azure PowerShell module
      Install-Module -Name Az 
            
      # Import the Azure PowerShell module
      Import-Module Az -Force
      
      #get function app
      $appName="valleywebapp09"
      $groupName="valleyrg54"
      $app =Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $groupName -Name $appName
      
      #get public certificate content
      $cerpath="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\siliconcert_714f1b774b99453784cac60599e29620.cer"
      $cerFileBytes = get-content $cerpath -Encoding Byte
      $cerblob=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cerFileBytes)
      
      $properties=@{
       blob =$cerblob;
       publicCertificateLocation="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
      }
      
      New-AzResource -ResourceName "$($appName)/testcer" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/publicCertificates" `
               -Properties $properties -ResourceGroupName $groupName
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I really appreciate it.  I didn't try your `az rest` suggestion because I don't want to add my public key certificate to my keyvault but to the certificates store of my WebApp.
I did try the Azure Powershell suggestion, but it won't start because it complains about  `The specified module 'Az.KeyVault' with version '4.10.1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.` and again I don't need access the my keyvault.

I can't understand why this is so difficult to do using command since it is so simple in the portal.;

Comment: I didn't try your az rest suggestion because I don't want to add my public key certificate to my keyvault but to the certificates store of my WebApp > Add your certificate in the keyvault and then import it into your web app with az rest command. As the az rest command will not work for local certificate, it will work for certificate in the key vault

Comment: I've added the certificate as a `Secret` to the keyvault and I've altered the code to use the secret from the keyvault to do the certificate checking and skip the certificate store of the WebApp. This is a doable workaround for us. Thanks for your help.